# cordova.js is throwing Uncaught TypeError with an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

LogCat is showing that cordova.js line 415 *(function checkArgs shown below)* is throwing an Uncaught TypeError causing my app to break.

**The log shows** `Uncaught TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "successCallback" of Device.getInfo: Expected Function, but got Undefined.`

The error only occurs when making an AJAX call... my AJAX call is below

```
function checkArgs(spec, functionName, args, opt_callee) {
    if (!moduleExports.enableChecks) {
        return;
    }
    var errMsg = null;
    var typeName;
    for (var i = 0; i < spec.length; ++i) {
        var c = spec.charAt(i),
            cUpper = c.toUpperCase(),
            arg = args[i];
        // Asterix means allow anything.
        if (c == '*') {
            continue;
        }
        typeName = utils.typeName(arg);
        if ((arg === null || arg === undefined) && c == cUpper) {
            continue;
        }
        if (typeName != typeMap[cUpper]) {
            errMsg = 'Expected ' + typeMap[cUpper];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (errMsg) {
        errMsg += ', but got ' + typeName + '.';
        errMsg = 'Wrong type for parameter "' + extractParamName(opt_callee || args.callee, i) + '" of ' + functionName + ': ' + errMsg;
        // Don't log when running unit tests.
        if (typeof jasmine == 'undefined') {
            console.error(errMsg);
        }
        throw TypeError(errMsg);
    }
}
```

My AJAX call:

```
var ajax = $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/tools/api/index.php",
    data: api,
    dataType:"json",
    async:async

});


ajax.done(function( response ) { 

// do this

});

ajax.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { 

// do that

});
```

*NOTE: I'm using build.phonegap.com and using version 3.3.0*

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** going through the all the source code which uses the function checkArgs I have found this. This is the only other function that uses checkArgs

```
/**
 * Get device info
 *
 * @param {Function} successCallback The function to call when the heading data is available
 * @param {Function} errorCallback The function to call when there is an error getting the heading data. (OPTIONAL)
 */
Device.prototype.getInfo = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    argscheck.checkArgs('fF', 'Device.getInfo', arguments);
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Device", "getDeviceInfo", []);
};
```

Why it's throwing error... I'm not sure

Comment: There will be no "success" because "same origin policy" will block your Request ;). Try it with JSONP. Also try to debug yourself with Charles Web Debugging Proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with pulling the `window.device` data.

I tried logging all the device at once `api.device = window.device` ... turns out device is a cordova function not an object with static values attached to it.

I had to change my code to

```
api.device = {};
api.device.name = device.name;
api.device.phonegap = device.phonegap;
api.device.platform = device.platform;
api.device.uuid = device.uuid;
api.device.version = device.version;
```

where before I just had

```
api.device = device;
```

Hope this can help someone else in the future.